# Getting INVALID REQUEST - Google autocomplte place api

Tags: android, google-map-place

Getting this error
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 9012: INVALID_REQUEST

```
FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest request = FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
                // Call either setLocationBias() OR setLocationRestriction().
                //.setLocationRestriction(bounds)
                .setCountries("IN")
                .setTypesFilter(Arrays.asList(TypeFilter.ADDRESS.toString()))
                .setSessionToken(token)
                .setQuery(query)
                .build();

        placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(request).addOnSuccessListener((response) -> {
            for (AutocompletePrediction prediction : response.getAutocompletePredictions()) {
                Log.i(TAG, prediction.getPlaceId());
                Log.i(TAG, prediction.getPrimaryText(null).toString());
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener((exception) -> {
            if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
                ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
                Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + apiException.getStatusCode());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what version of google places sdk you are using but for me this got broken after upgrading from 2.x to 3.0.0.
I've successfully worked it out for now by calling `setTypesFilter("address")` lowercased.

There's an [open issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/261035620) so I guess we'll have to wait until the google team fix this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using google places sdk version 3.0.0, use `PlaceTypes.ADDRESS`.

```
setTypesFilter(listOf(PlaceTypes.ADDRESS))
```

checkout the example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/client-migration#:%7E:text=.asList(-,PlaceTypes,-.ADDRESS))